# How to have the .max() return the i32 datatype?

Tags: rust, casting

I have the following code:

```
impl Solution {
    
    pub fn max_sliding_window(nums: Vec<i32>, k: i32) -> Vec<i32> {
        let mut result = vec![];
        for i in 0..nums.len() as i32 - (k - 1) {
            //println!("{}", nums[i as usize..(i + k) as usize].iter().max());
            result.push(nums[i as usize..(i + k) as usize].iter().max());
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

And I want to return the max value of each k sized window starting from the beginning of the nums vector to the end. However, the `.iter().max()` form is returning a `std::option::Option` type and not a i32 type. I also tried `as i32` but that is not allowed. How to fix this?

Comment: First you should decide what you want to happen when the vec is empty or k is negative. Then you should have a look at the methods of [Option](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html).

Answer (score 2):

`max()` returns an `Option` because there is no sensible value to return in the case of an empty iterator.

You need to deal with the `Option` and provide something reasonable in this case. For example `0`:

```
pub fn max_sliding_window(nums: Vec<i32>, k: i32) -> Vec<i32> {
    let mut result = vec![];
    for i in 0..nums.len() as i32 - (k - 1) {
        result.push(
            nums[i as usize..(i + k) as usize]
                .iter()
                .max()
                .copied() // because the iterator is over &i32 and you need i32
                .unwrap_or(0),
        );
    }
    return result;
}
```

---

n.b. as [Denys Séguret commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68058895/how-to-have-the-max-return-the-i32-datatype#comment120291369_68058895) above you also need to properly handle the case where `k` is negative: your code will panic as written.